# How to store unique visits in Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to know how many people visited each blog page. For that, I have a column in the Blogs table (MS SQL DB) to keep the total visits count. But I also want the visits to be as unique as possible.
So I keep the user's unique Id and blog Id in the Redis cache, and every time a user visits a page, I check if she has visited this page before, if not, I will increase the total visit count.

My question is, what is the best way of storing such data?
Currently, I create a key like this "project-visit-{blogId}-{userId}" and use StringSetAsync and StringGetAsync. But I don't know if this method is efficient or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using a cookie? You can probably use it to reference the data in your cache.

Comment: No, the user may clear her cache and visit a page a hundred times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can sacrifice some precision, the HyperLogLog (HLL) probabilistic data structure is a great solution for counting unique visits because:

- It only uses 12K of memory, and those are fixed - they don't grow with the number of unique visits
- You don't need to store user data, which makes your service more privacy-oriented

The HyperLogLog algorithm is really smart, but you don't need to understand its inner workings in order to use it, some years ago Redis added it as a data structure. So all you, as a user, need to know is that **with HyperLogLogs you can count unique elements (visits) in a fixed memory space of 12K, with a 0.81% margin of error**.

Let's say you want to keep a count of unique visits per day; you would have to have one HyperLogLog per day, named something like `cnt:page-name:20200917` and every time a user visits a page you would add them to the HLL:

```
> PFADD cnt:page-name:20200917 {userID}
```

If you add the same user multiple time, they will still only be counted once.
To get the count you run:

```
> PFCOUNT cnt:page-name:20200917
```

You can change the granularity of unique users by having different HLLs for different time intervals, for example `cnt:page-name:202009` for the month of September, 2020.

This quick explainer lays it out pretty well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAL2dxl1fsE

This blog post might help too: https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/counting/hyperloglog/

And if you're curious about the internal implementation Antirez's release post is a great read: http://antirez.com/news/75

NOTE: Please note that with this solution you lose the information of which user visited that page, you only have the count

Comment: Does it have a memory limit? Can I have a log for a page that keeps all the visits for that page, regardless of time?

Comment: There is a limit of number of elements that will saturate the HLL, but it's very high, much higher than the number of humans on Earth, so you should be ok. :)
And yes, if you don't need any granularity, you can use a single HLL for a page, and it will show you the number of unique visits since you created it (the HLL.)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not atomic, unless you wrap the get and set operation in a transaction or Lua script.

A better solution is to save `project-visit-{blogId}-{userId}` into a Redis set. When you get a visit, call `SADD` add an item into the set. Redis adds a new item to the set, only if the user has not visited this page before. If you want to get the total count, just call `SCARD` to get the size of the set.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the back-end technology (programming language etc.), you can use Redis stream. It is a very new feature in Redis 5 and allows you to define publisher and subscriber to a topic (stream) created in Redis. Then, in each user visit, you commit a new record (of course, async) to this stream. You can hold whatever info you want in that record (user ip, id etc..).

Defining a key for each unique visit is not a good idea at all, because:

- It makes the life harder for redis GC
- Performance, comparing the use-case, is not comparable to Stream, specially if you use that instance of redis for other purposes
- Constantly collecting these unique visits and processing them is not efficient. You have to always scan through all keys

Conclusion:
If you want to use Redis, go with Redis Stream. If Redis can be changed, go with Kafka for sure (or a similar technology).